# Get the Class from li with specific position with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to make an script that allows me to check the class of an specific li acording with a position, by example :

```
<ul id='check_passengers'>
    <li>user one</li>
    <li>user two</li>
    <liclass='user-checked'>user three</li>
    <li>user four</li>
    <li>user five</li>
<ul>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var position_to_search = 2;
var class_of_ul = $('#check_passengers li:' + position_to_search).attr('class');
console.log('User on position 3 : ' + class_of_ul);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with jQuery's [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var position_to_search = 2;
  var class_of_ul = $('#check_passengers li:eq(' + position_to_search+')').attr('class');
  console.log('User on position 3 : ' + class_of_ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='check_passengers'>
  <li>user one</li>
  <li>user two</li>
  <li class='user-checked'>user three</li>
  <li>user four</li>
  <li>user five</li>
<ul>
```

OR: with [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is more cleaner:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var position_to_search = 2;
  var class_of_ul = $(`#check_passengers li:eq(${ position_to_search})`).attr('class');
  console.log('User on position 3 : ' + class_of_ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='check_passengers'>
  <li>user one</li>
  <li>user two</li>
  <li class='user-checked'>user three</li>
  <li>user four</li>
  <li>user five</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly I was searching for.

Comment: I did mark, but i have 13 of rep, still can't vote, otherwise if you can vote on favor for this answer when i have 15 rep I will vote at favor for your answer, thank you a lot.

Comment: @MiguelTorres, you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.....And this will make you eligible for upvote.....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use css selectors for this:

- Nth-of-type
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type
- Nth-child https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var position_to_search = 3;
  var class_of_ul = $('#check_passengers li:nth-child('+ position_to_search +'n)').attr('class');
  console.log('User on position 3 : ' + class_of_ul);
});
```

Comment: Link only answers should generally be comments since you aren't adding much of your own information.

Answer (score 0):

use the css [:nth-child(position)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector for it. Note that the `indexing` starts from index `1`

like below

```
<ul id='check_passengers'>
    <li>user one</li>
    <li>user two</li>
    <liclass='user-checked'>user three</li>
    <li>user four</li>
    <li>user five</li>
<ul>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var position_to_search = 2;
       var class_of_ul = $('#check_passengers li:nth-child(' + position_to_search + ')')
   .attr('class');
       console.log('User on position 2 : ' + class_of_ul);
   });
</script>
```